# Como hacer una consulta de MYSQL con WHERE condicional

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Buenos dias a todos, necesito una ayuda y no se me cae una idea

Estoy armando una consulta para una base de datos, la cual me devuelve un
resultado (Tabla de la izquierda) que contiene una lista de empleados, y el
importe que cobraron por mes. A esta consulta, tengo que agregarle un filtro,
no se si un WHERE o deberia emplear CASE o IF, para que, si cobro en el mes "2",
no levante el registro del mes 1 del mismo empleado, asi mismo, de no cumplirse
esa condicion, que solo levante el mes "1"

Mi idea es que el resultado final, sea el de la Tabla de la derecha.

No soy alguien que pida ayuda, o "quiera que hagan su trabajo por el", pero en este
caso, estoy bloqueado, no se me ocurre como hacer.

En PHP pude hacerlo tranquilo manipulando arrays multidimensionales, pero la cuestion
es que tengo que hacerlo en MySQL, y ahi es donde me bloqueo

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias a todos!

[image: Ejemplo de las tabla de entrada y de salida]

Comment: muestra lo que llevas de la consulta y la estructura de las tablas

Comment: Gabriel, al menos muestra cómo están constituidas tus tablas. Hay una instrucción que te da esa información: **`SHOW CREATE TABLE  tu-tabla;`** ejecútala por cada tabla implicada y [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/131829/edit) colocando esos datos, los cuales son esenciales para poder ayudarte.

Comment: El hecho es que es demasiado extenso y los unicos datos relevantes son los que muestro en la imagen

La tabla representada a la izquierda, seria el **SELECT **

Asimismo, si necesitan los tipos de campo, podria decirte que Persona y Mes con VARCHAR y Valor INT

Answer (score 0):

La instrucción WHERE permite enunciar las condiciones de la
selección.
Ejemplo:
Si deseamos seleccionar el código de proveedor, nombre del
proveedor y su población, para aquellos que estén en la zona 2.
SELECT CODPRO, NOMBRE, POBLACIÓN
FROM PROVEEDOR
WHERE ZONA=2;
Las columnas especificadas en las instrucciones SELECT y
WHERE deben pertenecer a la(s) tabla(s) indicada(s).
Si en la expresión lógica se utilizan caracteres, estos deberán
estar entre los signos ‘ ‘.
Los operadores lógicos son los siguientes: =, <, >, >=, <=, !=.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu columna de mes fuera numérica, podrías obtener el máximo mes en donde una persona tiene registro:

```
SELECT max(mes) as mes, persona FROM tu_tabla GROUP BY persona
```

Y obtendrías

```
mes | persona
____|________
1   | Juan
2   | Gabriel
2   | Pedro
```

Luego podrías usar esa subconsulta para filtrar tus datos:

```
SELECT t1.persona, t1.mes, t1.valor
FROM tu_tabla t1
JOIN (SELECT max(mes) as mes, persona FROM tu_tabla GROUP BY persona) t2 USING (mes, persona);
```

Si tu columna tiene en cambio los nombres de los meses, necesitarás pasar por una tabla diccionario que relacione el número del mes con su nombre, pero confío en que con esta respuesta quedarás bien orientado.